# How to Remove only Special Characters without encoding or decoding the URL and text in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have text area and my text will be like this,

Exception Handling,

Mysql Prepared Statments,

₳ ฿ ￠ ₡ ¢ ₢ ₵ ₫ € ￡ £ ₤ ₣ ƒ ₲ ₭ ₥ ₦ ₱ ＄ $ ₮ ₩ ￦ ¥ ￥ ₴ ¤ ₰ ៛ ₪ ₯ ₠ ₧ ₨ ௹ ﷼ ㍐ ৲ ৳ ₹

https://github.com/airbrake/phpbrake/blob/master/src/ErrorHandler.php

I need to remove all these special characters without disturbing others text in the text area.
I have tried many regex and replace functions, but it decodes the text also.

My Expected output is,
Exception Handling, 
Mysql Prepared Statments,
https://github.com/airbrake/phpbrake/blob/master/src/ErrorHandler.php

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the relevant information into the question itself.

Comment: How are the files you linked to related to your question?

Comment: there is an unclear point in your question, "but it decodes the text also": if there is a special encoding, you should precise it in the question, and maybe also what is "decoded" in the process. An original value / expected result / actual result example could be useful here

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "abc's test#s";
str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "");
```

use this method. It will remove all the special characters.

Comment: have tried this, but i have a URL in my textarea that will get decoded if i use this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "")` to filter string characters other than special charactes. But this will leave empty spaces so you can further add
`.replace( / +/g, ' ' )` to just get one space if there is more than one

```js
var str = "₳This ฿ was ￠ ₡ a dummy ¢ ₢ ₵ ₫ € ￡ text£ ₤ ₣ ƒin string ₲ ₭ ₥ ₦ ₱ ＄ $ ₮ ₩ ￦ ¥ ￥ ₴ ¤ ₰containing  ៛ ₪ ₯ ₠ ₧ ₨ may௹ ﷼ ㍐ ৲special ৳ ₹ characters"
 
console.log(str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "").replace( / +/g, ' ' ))
```